# .htaccess redirection issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working in a site which has been developed in **codeigniter**,
To remove index.php from url I wrote rewrite rule in htaccess, now , there is anotheher need to be arise, that is I need to replace http:// to www in url,for that I wrote the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vrinfosystem.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.vrinfosystem.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but I got issues, the stylesheet and js are no found.
I changed the base url too but it didn't help.
if I wrote following line above the `HTTP_HOST`
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
the it will work fine but the index.php will retain in url.
Ho can I solve this issue?

Comment: There should be only one [L], others rule below it will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

are u sure u have changed your config?

if you don't go to application>config>config.php than scroll down till you find this

```
$config[‘index_page’] = 'index.php';
```

change it too

```
$config[‘index_page’] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a group of different scripts for this. This is the only one that worked for me across several sites

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php| (.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```